# Is it worth to add automatic tagging feature?

Tags: discussion, tags

I wonder, is it worth to have automatic tagging feature for several tags here, on stackoverflow. For example, if somebody sets tag "sql-server" the tag "sql" is automatically added. The reason is I'm trying to build a list of interesting/ignored tags and it seems this will never be finished, day after day I see new and new tags.
I suppose there should be a set of root tags including such as c,java,c++, etc. And when somebody sets a new tag - the choice of root tags should be provided for automatic addition (or in such a way that one is obliged to make the choice). 
Of course some resources are needed to revise already existed tags.

Comment: you can just use a wildcard `sql*` to be interested in all tags starting with sql.

Comment: An old feature request for tag implications can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags). As far as whether it is worth it, though, I don't think so. The limit of 5 tags makes an implication system very cumbersome to handle.

Comment: Then, sorry for repetition. I didn't know about meta.stackoverflow branch. Actually wildcard doesn't work for all cases and lack of systematic in tagging sometimes annoying.

Comment: Well, yes. I've found a lot of similar questions here (one more is Addition of implicit tags.). So, this is really worth as so much people of this opinion. 
And by the way, that questions are not gone negative as mine. I've even described my vision on the method of implementing this.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta tend to [imply that someone disagrees with your view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-work/47635#47635). Whoever it is may not have seen the previous requests, and just disagrees with tag implications.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a video Christian Heilmann of Yahoo (YQL) put together:

> Autotagging Stack Overflow with Yahoo's term extractor and YQL
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SA4Et1DiVbE

In general I think it would create more problems than it solves.

Comment: Is *that* where the `[programmer]` tag came from? Ughhhhhhh...

Comment: Honestly, I did not understand how this video is related to what I've proposed.

Comment: @Pmod: I think it was aimed at my response.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would rather have a list of suggested tags provided by a parse/analysis of the original question, but that's an extremely complex feature that would provide little long-term value.

Comment: Why not making things simpler? Suggested tags based on already set tags?