# .Net tag (ab)use

Tags: discussion, tags

I was playing around with my [stackapps app](https://stackapps.com/questions/933/stacktagz-track-the-topics-you-are-interested-in-over-time) and noticed a trend that a .Net tag is largely useless and mostly follows [c#]. Have a look at [Jon Skeet](http://stacktagz.com/#/stackoverflow.com/22656/jon-skeet) or [Marc Gravell](http://stacktagz.com/#/stackoverflow.com/23354/marc-gravell). There is a clear correlation between the two but instead of what seems logical - that c# questions are a subset of .Net questions, it's the other way around. It's almost as if some users tag their questions with [.net] and some don't.

I guess what I am trying to say is whether or not there could be some smarts included in the tag system in the way of "tag A implies tag B". Or even something more elaborate like "C# implies .net OR Mono, you must pick one of those".

Does that make sense? Would it be usable?

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53331/is-it-worth-to-add-automatic-tagging-feature.

Comment: Looks like both hierarchical tags and .Net tags have been discussed before. I guess those few related questions kinda answer my question.

Comment: This one is most useful - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags - except for it's about half of C# questions that are tagged [.net] and the other half ain't Mono

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think they can or should be logically different.

A question which is about the C# *language* doesn't really need the .NET tag.

A question about how to use a particular API doesn't really need the C# tag - although it may help in terms of suggesting the language for code samples.