# Which Fortran tag(s) should I use?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There exist a multitude of tags related to the Fortran language. As far as I can infer from the descriptions they are meant to be grouped like this:

- The programming language itself: [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran)
- Compilers: [ifort](/questions/tagged/ifort), [gfortran](/questions/tagged/gfortran), [pgi](/questions/tagged/pgi), etc.
- The Standard and its versions: [fortran77](/questions/tagged/fortran77), [fortran90](/questions/tagged/fortran90), [fortran95](/questions/tagged/fortran95), etc.

What I see, however, is the questions are usually tagged with either [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran), or one of the standard-related flags, or a combination of all that. This results in questions that are scattered over all the tags. I guess, it is not obvious which tag to choose.

Maybe it would be better to rename those tags to something more self-explanatory like `fortran-standard-77` or `fortran-language` (Assuming my interpretation of the tags is correct, of course).

Another idea would be to automatically tag all questions filed under one of the above tags under [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran) as well. Is that technically possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran) should be on all the questions, and then the specific tag for the compiler or version would be added on.  I definitely don't think we need to add `fortran-` as a prefix on all of them, and don't need to create a specific `fortran-language` tag.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, I meant we also don't need a `fortran-language` tag, I'll edit to make clearer.

Comment: So, I should always use [tag:fortran] and then specify the topic further... What about a question that was filed in [tag:fortran90] alone but has nothing to do with anything specific to the standard - just some programming question. Should I re-tag the question and delete the reference to [tag:fortran90]?

Comment: If you're sure that there is nothing specific to the version of the language, yes.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically add the [tag:fortran] tag?

Comment: Ah, ok... it is not - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53331/is-it-worth-to-add-automatic-tagging-feature

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: if you tag a question with just fortran, I'm going to reply in whatever form I'm most comfortable with for your problem at hand. Probably F95+. If you said fortran AND fortran77, then I would know not to use advanced features.

Comment: OK, so the tags are not so much "related to the standard" but more of a "I prefer to code in that standard"?