# How important is comprehensive tag coverage?

Tags: discussion, tags, review, community-standards, untagged-questions

I have read a number of the tag-rated questions here on meta, searching for any consensus on human-moderated auto-tagging.  [Here is a great one.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53331/is-it-worth-to-add-automatic-tagging-feature)

I got thinking about this because I've been on a 'campaign' to add tag coverage for some areas of Rails questions.  The pattern is easy: the questions include certain words, but are rarely tagged appropriately.  About 80% of the question actually need the tag, and the rest have arbitrary inclusion, or were confused, etc.

**I am trying to evaluate if the community truly benefits from this**.

My dopamine sensors get stim'd by the *curatorial* activity, but I want to be sure this is valuable to anyone.

---

If it were of value, we could return focus to the question linked above, and the references in there to machine-learning studies done on auto-tagging.

We could use such search approaches to create a review queue for tag suggestions