# Are tags one dimensional?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we make tags imply other tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags)

To be specific - what's the approach of tagging questions when SO already has general tag for a technology (e.g. `extjs`) and couple specific tags for specific versions (`extjs4` and `extjs4.1`).

If I'm asking question about ExtJs 4.1.0 I would apply `extjs4.1`, but do I have to apply always general tag `extjs`?

Or is there way to make tags nested? Something like:

```
extjs
 -- extjs3
 -- extjs4
 -- extjs4.1
```

Comment: Yes, tags are "one dimensional". Nested tags were [proposed and declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags).

Comment: So I should tag questions using both general tag and version specific tag?

Comment: Can u give me an example where it doesn't make sense? And if you can post all this as an answer I'd be happy to mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, tags are "one dimensional", nested tags were [proposed and declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags).

I think tagging a question as [extjs](/questions/tagged/extjs)[extjs4](/questions/tagged/extjs4) or just [extjs4](/questions/tagged/extjs4) is fine, but [extjs4.1](/questions/tagged/extjs4.1) is too specific to be useful. You only get five tags per question, no sense in wasting a tag for a minor version, you can always tell us the exact version you are using in the question text.

Comment: IIRC, you should only use the tiny version tags if the question is related to something added there--not just 'cos you're using the version. Also, it looks like you site-copied your profile and your meta profile went along the lines of your old gravatar. Boom.

Comment: @Manishearth The profile change was intentional, I thought I'd revert to my serious self everywhere at least for the duration of the [awesome Programmers contest](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/programmers-se-contest-the-complete-outline).