# Tag Subsets (or New Tag Synonyms)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we make tags imply other tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags)

I am going to define the problem by providing a quick example: Let's say I am developing a `Rails` application (`v 3.2.1`) and have a problem.  So, naturally after almost giving up on Google, I began to post the question on `StackOverflow`.  The problem comes when I am choosing the tags - The following all accurately define my application environment to some degree of precision:

[ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) : More than 70k questions (77 asked today)
[ruby-on-rails-3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3) : More than 25k questions (36 asked today)
[ruby-on-rails-3.2](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.2) : Around 370 questions (7 asked today) 
[ruby-on-rails-3.2.1](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.2.1) : Around 55 questions (8 asked *this month*)

Ideally, I should choose just [ruby-on-rails-3.2.1](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.2.1), but a quick glance at the number of questions asked with that tag (recently) makes me act otherwise.  While, I understand that [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) is meant to signify `Rails 1.0`, I doubt many people are still on that version.  Looking at some recent rails questions confirms this belief as it seems that most people include two-three tags related to the question such as: [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails); [ruby-on-rails-3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3) ... (and so on).

There is usually no way for them to include all the four above tags without adequately defining the problem they have in tags - and thus often leave out [ruby-on-rails-3.2.1](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.2.1) (the most precise tag).

The solution I propose is `tag-subsets` - such that choosing [ruby-on-rails-3.2.1](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.2.1) would automatically select the other three tags (and they don't count towards the five-tag limit).  Note, that these are different from `tag-synonyms`.

For the sake of a discussion - there is another solution I thought of (although I like the idea of `tag-subsets`):

- Rename tags so they precisely include the version number.  So, for instance [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) be renamed to [ruby-on-rails-1.0](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-1.0) ;  [ruby-on-rails-3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3) be renamed to [ruby-on-rails-3.0](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.0) and so on.  This would force users to choose the right tag (there is only one "right" tag ever).

The major problem I see with this is the issue of backward compatibility.  As mentioned earlier, there are a lot of questions with the [ruby-on-rails-3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3) tag that don't really pertain to `Rails 3.0`.

The other concern with forcing version numbers is that only few of the questions are actually version specific and if someone wants to ask a generic `Rails` related question, then, having to choose the version number may not be the best idea.

Note, while I use `Ruby-on-Rails` as an example - I see similar problems in other areas as well where `tag-subsets` would be useful.  For instance: [python](/questions/tagged/python) ; [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) ; [python-2.6](/questions/tagged/python-2.6).

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131570/automatically-adding-superset-tags

Comment: Ahhh.. my bad.  I didn't see that!  Now I see plenty of other people have asked similar questions (using all sorts of different terminology!) and they have all been linked to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags

I am wondering if there's any scope of re-opening the discussion given that most attempts have simply been closed as duplicate with a link to the post from 2009!

Comment: [tag:ruby-on-rails] doesn't mean RoR 1.0, it means RoR without specifying a version. If there are questions that are specific to RoR 1 and do not apply to other versions of RoR, they should be tagged [tag:ruby-on-rails-1]. For RoR, Python or anything else, use the generic tag; only use a tag with a version number if your question is absolutely specific to this version and is irrelevant to people using other versions.

Comment: @Gilles Interestingly, there is no tag `Ruby-on-Rails-1`, just like there is no tag `Ruby-on-Rails-3.0`  (just `Ruby-on-Rails-3`).  I always figured that the first version of release of a specific version did not have the number after it (just like the first movie in any series usually isn't called `<MovieName> 1` - its just `<MovieName>` and then `<MovieName> 2`)