# Could we make tags *optionally* imply others?

Tags: feature-request, tags

There are many tags that imply others. See a highly related question:
[Could we make tags imply other tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags). One of the reasons [against](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags) it is that it makes it more likely to hit the 5 tag limit. There are probably other reasons against as well.

My question is could we make tags *optionally* imply others. Like, if you use a tag, it will ask if you want to use other related tags.

The reason tag implication is good is so by following, say, [python](/questions/tagged/python), I also will follow anyone who tags questions [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) or such (since most of them would be tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python) anyway).

Tags imply each other anyway (people automatically add more general versions of tags already); it would just be nice if there was technical assistance in this process.

Comment: Note that tag suggestions [*already* exist](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tWK7D.png), but are created based on analysis of the post content (not other tags). This could perhaps be an extension of that?